# Kendo TreeView with initial item load its children menu from remote data

Tags: javascript, asp.net-mvc, razor, kendo-ui, asp.net-mvc-5

I have kendo treeview to show history list, so initially i have 1 item then load its children from remote data. Here is my razor code :

```
@(Html.Kendo().TreeView()
      .Name("tvHistory")
      .Animation(animation => animation.Expand(open =>
                 {
                     open.Expand(ExpandDirection.Vertical);
                     open.Fade(FadeDirection.In);
                 }))
      .Items(treeview => treeview.Add().Text("History").Id(Model.Id.ToString()))
      .DataTextField("Description")
      .AutoBind(false)
      .DataSource(dataSource => dataSource.Read(read => read.Action("History", "Reservation")))
      )
```

So technically when this "**History**" item being clicked it will call datasource read action and load its children items from controller. Yet its produce an error in console instead of calling the controller. [image: error console]

Here is my controller code and the class that I return to client

```
[HttpGet]
public ActionResult History(int id)
{
    IList<ReservationHistory> histories = _reservationService.GetHistoryFor(id).DataList;
    IList<ReservationHistoryViewModel> viewModels = histories.ToModel<ReservationHistory, ReservationHistoryViewModel>();

    return Json(viewModels, JsonRequestBehavior.AllowGet);
}

public class ReservationHistoryViewModel
{
    public int Id { get; set; }
    public int ReservationId { get; set; }
    public string Description { get; set; }
}
```

any suggestion to fix this? Thanks

Comment: By any chance are you sending a null item across such that Model.Id.ToString() would fail?

Comment: no, i assure that Model already loaded from controller and i also have tried to using static value for id.. This widget was rendered successfully, yet the onclick menu history was producing an error..